# Настройка OpenDKIM для нескольких доменов.

Tags: email, dkim, ubuntu

Всем привет. Встала задача настроить цифровую подпись для нескольких доменов. До этого работало с одним доменом и нормально.

**Старый вариант конфига /etc/opendkim.conf**

```
Domain                  dimka3210.ru
KeyFile                 /etc/postfix/dkim.key
Selector                mail
SOCKET                  inet:8891@localhost
```

Ключик генерировался командой

```
opendkim-genkey -t -s mail -d dimka3210.ru
```

Потом ключик был просто скопирован

```
cp mail.private /etc/postfix/dkim.key
```

Ну и добавлены TXT запись в домен и соответствующие настройки в /etc/postfix/main.cf и /etc/default/opendkim. Там ничего интересного. И все это взлетело и работало.

Теперь попробовал настроить несколько доменов. Нашёл [эту](http://www.doless.ru/nastraivaem-debian-postfix-opendkim.html/comment-page-1#comment-80791) статью и все сделал по ней. Начал с одного домена, того же dimka3210.ru.

Вот такие файлы у меня получились

```
# cat KeyTable 
default._domainkey.dimka3210.ru

# cat SigningTable 
dimka3210.ru default._domainkey.dimka3210.ru

# cat TrustedHosts 
127.0.0.1
localhost
dimka3210.ru
```

**Новый вариант конфига**

```
Syslog                  yes
SyslogSuccess           yes
LogWhy                  yes

ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts

SigningTable            /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
KeyTable                /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
UMask                   002
X-Header                yes
RemoveOldSignatures     yes
ReportAddress           myaddress@gmail.com
SendReports             yes
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
UserID                  opendkim:opendkim

Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
```

**Первое** отличие которое я заметил, так это то, что автор статьи дал немного другую команду для генерацию ключей

```
opendkim-genkey -D /etc/opendkim/beut.ru/ –d beut.ru -s default
```

Почему, я пока не знаю. Но ключа "t" тут нет.
**Второе**, он пишет обратить внимание на права, но я их все перепробовал и 555, и 444, и 600, и 744.... не работает.
Отправляю командой

```
sendemail -f test@dimka3210.ru -t myaddress@gmail.com -u "Тест dkim" -o message-charset="utf-8" -m "Текст теста"
```

Ответ службы

```
Jan 04 14:30:47 srv-1 sendemail[23059]: ERROR => Received:  451 4.7.0 resource unavailable
```

В syslog пишет

```
Jan  4 14:30:47 srv-1 postfix/smtpd[23046]: connect from localhost[::1]
Jan  4 14:30:47 srv-1 postfix/smtpd[23046]: 6EE453025D4: client=localhost[::1]
Jan  4 14:30:47 srv-1 postfix/cleanup[23054]: 6EE453025D4: message-id=<256461.049054877-sendEmail@srv-1>
Jan  4 14:30:47 srv-1 opendkim[23035]: 6EE453025D4: SSL error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
Jan  4 14:30:47 srv-1 opendkim[23035]: 6EE453025D4: dkim_eom(): resource unavailable: d2i_PrivateKey_bio() failed
Jan  4 14:30:47 srv-1 postfix/cleanup[23054]: 6EE453025D4: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from localhost[::1]: 4.7.0 resource unavailable; from=<test@dimka3210.ru> to=<myaddress@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<srv-1>
Jan  4 14:30:47 srv-1 postfix/smtpd[23046]: disconnect from localhost[::1]
Jan  4 14:30:57 srv-1 postfix/smtp[23025]: 4D4E83025CA: to=<myaddress@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.165.26]:25, delay=57, delays=0.68/0/55/0.69, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1420371063 b5si58123528laa.32 - gsmtp)
Jan  4 14:30:57 srv-1 postfix/qmgr[22661]: 4D4E83025CA: removed
```

По ошибке

```
dkim_eom(): resource unavailable: d2i_PrivateKey_bio() failed
```

Я нагуглил что opendkim не может прочитать конфиги, ну или у них права не верные. Но как я писал выше, я их уже даже методом тыка пробовал перебирать. Может кто-то знает как это пофиксить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил сам короче. В `/etc/opendkim.conf` нужно добавить

```
Mode sv
```

Папке `/etc/opendkim` ставим права `555`
Папкам с ключами ставим `555`
Ключам ставим права `440`

Перезапускаем `opendkim` и все становится хорошо.

[image]